# Python - metaclass changes variable scope from instance to class

Tags: python, metaclass

Running following code:

```py
class NonMeta:
    def __new__(cls):
        x = super().__new__(cls)
        x.attr = 100
        return x


class Meta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, dct):
        x = super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, dct)
        x.attr = 100
        return x


class WithMeta(metaclass=Meta):
    pass


print(WithMeta.attr)
print(NonMeta.attr)
```

results in

```
/usr/bin/python3.7 /home/lookash/PycharmProjects/PythonLearning/classes.py
100
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lookash/PycharmProjects/PythonLearning/classes.py", line 20, in <module>
    print(NonMeta.attr)
AttributeError: type object 'NonMeta' has no attribute 'attr'
```

Why attr from the WithMeta class is a class variable while it is an instance variable in the NonMeta class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instances of a metaclass are the classes that declare they will use it (and their subclasses). So when you do `x.attr = 100` in `Meta.__new__`, `x` is a class (an instance of the metaclass, `WithMeta` in this case).

That's different from when you run the same line in `NonMeta.__new__`, where `x` is an instance of `NonMeta`, and the class itself doesn't ever get assigned an `attr` attribute.

For this reason, it might be a good idea to change the code in your `__new__` methods to use different and better names than `x`. In `NonMeta`, a good name might be `self`, since that's the traditional name for an instance within a method. In `Meta`, you might use `cls`, since the instance is going to be a class.

Answer (score 2):

Inside `NonMeta.__new__`, `x` is an instance of `NonMeta`, so the assignment to `x.attr` is creating an instance attribute for the instance `x`.

Inside `Meta.__new__`, `x` is an instance of `Meta`, namely a new class. In this case, `x` is the class `WithMeta`, so the assignment to `x.attr` creates a class attribute.

The `class` statement is, in some sense, syntactic sugar for a call to the metatype. That is,

```
class WithMeta(metaclass=Meta):
    pass
```

is equivalent to

```
WithMeta = Meta('WithMeta', (object,), {})
# == Meta.__new__(Meta, 'WithMeta', (object,), {})
```

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent code without a metaclass to what you are doing *with* the metaclass is simply:

```py
class NonMeta:
    x = 100
```

The `__new__` method defined in classes is called only when an instance of the class is created - it won't run bedore that. And in this code:

```py
class NonMeta:
    def __new__(cls):
        x = super().__new__(cls)
        x.attr = 100
        return x
```

What returns from `super().__new__(cls)` and is stored in `x` is just the instance itself - the same object that is passed with the name `self` to regular instance methods (including `__init__`).

The Metaclass, on the other hand, have its `__new__` (and `__init__`) methods run when the class is created. In an ordinary module import, that takes place when a `class` statement, along with its body, is executed. At the end of the body, the Python runtime have all the information needed to create a new class, and the metaclass' `__new__` is called. Whatever it returns **becomes the class**. And since its return value have the `x` attribute set, it is already visible on the class.